# Reading lines beyond SUB in Python

Tags: python, ascii

Newbie question. In Python 2.7.2., I have a problem reading text files which accidentally seem to contain some control characters. Specifically, the loop

`for line in f`

will cease without any warning or error as soon as it comes across a line containing the `SUB` character (ascii hex code 1a). When using `f.readlines()` the result is the same. Essentially, as far as Python is concerned, the file is finished as soon as the first `SUB` character is encountered, and the last value assigned `line` is the line up to that character.

Is there a way to read beyond such a character and/or to issue a warning when encountering one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Windows systems `0x1a` is the End-of-File character.  You'll need to open the file in binary mode in order to get past it:

```
f = open(filename, 'rb')
```

The downside is you will lose the line-oriented nature and have to split the lines yourself:

```
lines = f.read().split('\r\n')  # assuming Windows line endings
```

Comment: for linux line endings, use `lines = f.read().split('\n')`

Answer (score 6):

Try opening the file in binary mode:

```
f = open(filename, 'rb')
```

Comment: thank you a thousand times.